# Целесообразность RAID1 на SSD

Tags: raid, ssd

Хотелось бы понять целесообразность создания RAID1 на дисках SSD.
Есть ли смысл вообще в этом? Очевидно, что основная задача, возлагаемая на зеркало - отказоустойчивость. В каких сценариях появляется целесообразность зеркала на SSD?

Comment: Думаю нет, они у тебя будут дохнуть вместе, т.к количество перезаписей там ограничено.

Comment: Зависит от задач возлагаемых на raid. Того, какими именно средствами он создается. И от характера его использования программами. (Например md в linux не паралелит обращения если один процесс читает блок данных превышающий размер страйпа, если процесса 2 - то паралелит). Так же не последнюю роль играет реальная пропускная способность и особенности организации моста (или внешнего контроллера) на матери . В общем делаете рейд и смотрите что на ваших конкретных задачах он дает